# Including jquery in a browserify build

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I'm trying to bundle jquery into my Browserify app so I don't have to load it from a CDN in my main html file.  I have installed jquery into my npm_modules

```
npm install jquery
```

and then added it to my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bwplans",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-browserify": "^5.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "latest",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "latest",
    "jshint-stylish": "latest",
    "jquery": "latest"
  }
}
```

and finally at the top of my module I'm requiring it:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

the build is running without errors but I'm still getting

```
$ is not defined
```

If I look in my built file, jquery is definitely being compiled in there, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa.

This works perfectly well.  The module that was throwing an error had not required jquery - I was looking at the wrong module.  All that was missing was a require.